# Is Threshold Logic Minimization (synthesis) NP-Hard, NP-Complete or NP or..

Tags: logic, optimization, np-complete

Consider a problem of generating a minimal threshold logic circuit for an arbitrary boolean function. This is akin to usual [circuit optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization), but gates are allowed to be any threshold (linearly separable) functions.

What complexity class is this problem?
I can not seem to find a paper that explicitly states it.

[Zhang, Li, and Sorin Cotofana (2005)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/81ca/2933b50d94db1ace2d6dab2148624764cd70.pdf) mention in the last paragraph that it is NP-complete. Is there a source that shows this? Or is it somehow obvious by analogy with conventional logic optimization?